# True or false: If $A$ is an $N\times N$ matrix with $A^4 - 2A^2 +5A -2I_n =0$, then $A$ is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Is there any property that relates inverse matrix and identity matrix?

Comment: Hint: Calculate $A(\frac12A^3-A+\frac52A)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$A \left( A^3 - 2A +5I \right)=\left( A^3 - 2A +5I \right)A=2 I_n$$